# Conditional selection in a GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-8.0, greatest-n-per-group

I am an SQL beginner and ran into the following problem. Consider a table with data on countries, cities within that country and their population:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    country VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    population INT
);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES
   ('Italy', 'Milano', 1000000), 
   ('Italy', 'Rome', 2000000), 
   ('Italy', 'Bologna', 800000), 
   ('Poland', 'Warszawa', 1000000), 
   ('Poland', 'Wroclaw', 700000);
```

I would like to write a query which returns the country name, alongside the population of its biggest city and the city name itself. The first two fields are straightforward using `GROUP BY`. However, I don't know how to include the name of the biggest city. I tried:

```
SELECT 
    country, MAX(population), city
FROM
    cities
WHERE
    population = (SELECT 
            MAX(population)
        FROM
            cities
        )
GROUP BY country, city;
```

but this selects only one record (the one about Rome). I'd like the query to return one record per country group, i.e. in this case Rome and Warszawa. The `WHERE` condition cannot be:

```
population = (SELECT 
            MAX(population)
        FROM
            cities
        GROUP BY country)
```

because then the subquery returns two rows, leading to Error 1242 in the main query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

A simple way of doing this is to use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) (manual [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) and function [descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)) window function - no need to use a `JOIN`. All of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NhTNMpy7):

I set up the table (see below - added two indexes) and then populated it with your data (see fiddle).

```
CREATE TABLE cities 
(
    country VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    population INT,

    CONSTRAINT cities_pk      PRIMARY KEY (country, city),
    KEY cities_city_ix (city, population)
  
);
```

Then, first thing is to run (this is by way of explanation):

```
SELECT
  country, city, population, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY country, population DESC) AS rn
FROM 
  cities;
```

Result:

```
country  city     population  rn
  Italy  Rome        2000000   1  <--- Italy's biggest city
  Italy  Milano      1000000   2
  Italy  Bologna      800000   3
 Poland  Warszawa    1000000   1  <--- Poland's   "      "
 Poland  Wroclaw      700000   2
```

So, now run this SQL picking out the top cities from the query above as the "pops" subquery (or derived table):

```
SELECT
  country, city, population
FROM
(
  SELECT
    country, city, population, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY country, population DESC) AS rn
  FROM 
    cities
) AS pops
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY country;
```

Result:

```
country  city      population
Italy    Rome         2000000
Poland   Warszawa     1000000
```

Window functions are **very** powerful and will repay any effort you put into learning them many times over. `ROW_NUMBER()` is more powerful than `FIRST_VALUE()` or `LAST_VALUE()` because it allows you to choose not only the top 1, but the top 2, 3... &c. Again, read & practice a bit until you've grokked them!

Just as an aside, I would append these lines to the bottom of the table definition - PK and an `INDEX` (or `KEY` - less typing :-) ).

```
CONSTRAINT cities_pk      PRIMARY KEY (country, city),
KEY cities_city_ix (city, population)
```

These appear to produce a nice plan - all indexes, no table scans! See fiddle.

```
EXPLAIN
-> Sort: pops.country  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
    -> Index lookup on pops using <auto_key0> (rn=1)
        -> Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0)
            -> Window aggregate: row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cities.country ORDER BY cities.country,cities.population desc ) 
                -> Sort: cities.country, cities.country, cities.population DESC  (cost=0.75 rows=5)
                    -> Index scan on cities using cities_city_ix
```

**Caveat:** The `EXPLAIN` was done on a minimal dataset - I would advise you to test **all** of the answers here on **your** hardware and **your** data so that you utilise the optimum solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your table has the data distribution similar to what a real countries/cities table would have (~200 countries, hundreds of thousands of cities), you can use a lateral query and improve its performance by creating an index on `(country, population)`.

It would benefit from a skip scan on `country`, and a lateral index scan on the index in a nested loop.

```
INSERT
INTO    cities (coutnry, city, population)
WITH    RECURSIVE q AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS value
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  value + 1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   value < 1000000
        )
SELECT  CONCAT('country', value % 200),
        CONCAT('city', value),
        FLOOR(RAND() * 10000000)
FROM    q;

CREATE INDEX ix_cities_country_population ON cities (country, population);

ANALYZE TABLE cities;
```

, and the query:

```
SELECT   first.*
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT country FROM cities) countries,
         LATERAL
         (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    cities
         WHERE   cities.country = countries.country
         ORDER BY
                 country DESC, population DESC
         LIMIT 1
         ) first
ORDER BY
         country;
```

The query completes in 20 ms on my VM.

Here's its plan:

```
-> Sort: `first`.country  (actual time=8.19..8.2 rows=200 loops=1)
    -> Stream results  (cost=3404 rows=202) (actual time=4.1..7.91 rows=200 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=3404 rows=202) (actual time=4.1..7.83 rows=200 loops=1)
            -> Invalidate materialized tables (row from countries)  (cost=160 rows=202) (actual time=4.01..4.07 rows=200 loops=1)
                -> Table scan on countries  (cost=155..160 rows=202) (actual time=4..4.05 rows=200 loops=1)
                    -> Materialize  (cost=155..155 rows=202) (actual time=4..4 rows=200 loops=1)
                        -> Covering index skip scan for deduplication on cities using ix_cities_country_population  (cost=135 rows=202) (actual time=0.0953..3.73 rows=200 loops=1)
            -> Table scan on first  (cost=2717..2717 rows=1) (actual time=0.0184..0.0185 rows=1 loops=200)
                -> Materialize (invalidate on row from countries)  (cost=2714..2714 rows=1) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=200)
                    -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=2714 rows=1) (actual time=0.0168..0.0168 rows=1 loops=200)
                        -> Index lookup on cities using ix_cities_country_population (country=countries.country) (reverse)  (cost=2714 rows=4956) (actual time=0.0165..0.0165 rows=1 loops=200)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but there's no table called countries? Big admirer of your site BTW - I'm just waiting for you to rewrite Linux in SQL! :-)

Comment: @Vérace: it's an alias, right there on the second line. Thanks!

Comment: Doh... <slaps forehead à la Homer Simpson!>

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the country and population as follows

```
SELECT A.country,A.city,A.pop population FROM
(SELECT country,city,population pop FROM cities) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT country,MAX(population) pop FROM cities GROUP BY country) B 
USING (country,pop);
```

Subquery A is just all rows in city table

Subquery B is all countries and its MAX city population

### UPDATE 2023-10-03 14:21 EDT

Here is your sample data and my query in a script

```
root@redwards-8CG8490YXM:~/DBASE# cat dzejkob.sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dzejkob;
CREATE DATABASE dzejkob;
USE dzejkob

CREATE TABLE cities (
    country VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    population INT
);

INSERT INTO cities VALUES
('Italy', 'Milano', 1000000),
('Italy', 'Rome', 2000000),
('Italy', 'Bologna', 800000),
('Poland', 'Warszawa', 1000000),
('Poland', 'Wroclaw', 700000);

SHOW CREATE TABLE cities\G
SELECT * FROM cities;

SELECT A.country,A.city,A.pop population FROM
(SELECT country,city,population pop FROM cities) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT country,MAX(population) pop FROM cities GROUP BY country) B
USING (country,pop);
root@redwards-8CG8490YXM:~/DBASE#
```

Here is the script executed

```
root@redwards-8CG8490YXM:~/DBASE# mysql --table < dzejkob.sql
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cities
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
+---------+----------+------------+
| country | city     | population |
+---------+----------+------------+
| Italy   | Milano   |    1000000 |
| Italy   | Rome     |    2000000 |
| Italy   | Bologna  |     800000 |
| Poland  | Warszawa |    1000000 |
| Poland  | Wroclaw  |     700000 |
+---------+----------+------------+
+---------+----------+------------+
| country | city     | population |
+---------+----------+------------+
| Italy   | Rome     |    2000000 |
| Poland  | Warszawa |    1000000 |
+---------+----------+------------+
root@redwards-8CG8490YXM:~/DBASE#
```

### UPDATE 2023-10-04 10:56 EDT

[As pointed out to me by ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331813/conditional-selection-in-a-group-by-clause#comment646303_331814), here is an update to the query

```
SELECT A.country,A.city,A.population
FROM cities A INNER JOIN
(SELECT country,MAX(population) pop FROM cities GROUP BY country) B
ON A.country=B.country AND A.population=B.pop;
```

NOTE : [Vérace's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/331821/877) is a way better solution

Comment: Thanks. That works, although I thought in SQL that would be a much simpler task.

Comment: Hey Vérace, you answer is way better than mine.